# Received the following error after creating contibution in backend

Tags: drupal

Please correct the following errors in the form fields below:
Select at least one option from Contribution(s).

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the form along with the error message?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange :) Can you please also mention your Civi CRM version number and what CMS you're using?

Answer (score 0):

One or more of the required field for contribution or a custom field related to contribution which is a required field value maybe missing. I would look in there first.